# Prove that $43^{101}+23^{101}$ is divisible by $66$ using modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $43^{101}+23^{101}$ is divisible by 66.
I was able to find it to be divisible by 22 but not by 66. Please help

Comment: Well, what is your expression $\pmod 3$?

Comment: It seems to me that none of the answers in the "duplicate" question use modular arithmetic. If that is important to you and you are not satisfied with the answer already given, I suggest you edit your question to clarify what you really need and say more about what you already know. (For example, how did you show the number is divisible by 22?)

Answer (score 4):

$43\equiv -23 \pmod{66}$

$43^{101}\equiv -(23^{101})\pmod{66}$

$43^{101}+23^{101}\equiv 0 \pmod{66}$